# Adding tabs to textarea's using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, textarea

I would like to allow literal `TAB` (`\t`) characters in my textarea's. However, the `TAB` key cycles to the next form element. Since this is expected I don't want to break that standard. Likewise, `CTRL + TAB` cycles browser tabs. Is there a recomended key-combo to allow people to enter an actual `TAB` inside a textarea?

For example, `CTRL + SPACE` doesn't seem to do anything, could that be used?

Also, how would I listen for these combos correctly?

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys  But seriously, as a user, I would find that behavior super annoying.  This behavior is not 'expected' in a text area.

Comment: @KenThompson, that's the point. I want to find an un-used combo that would not effect users - only offer additional functionally if they wanted.

Comment: Users will hit the TAB key and expect it to enter a tab (or spaces) in the text area.  If that's what you are trying to achieve, you don't need a plugin for that.  You just have to prevent propagation.    Just google "allow TAB in text area" and you will find your answer.  Your question made it sound like you were trying to make TAB go to another element..and require users not liking this to use (and memorize) a different combination.  That is what I would find annoying.

Comment: @KenThompson, more users will expect hitting the TAB key to cycle than insert an actual tab. I don't want to break this functionally.

Comment: Unless it's just a one or two liner I disagree.  But I guess unless we take a poll we'll never know for sure.

Comment: Why not let the user insert `\t` in textarea, and later parse it as a `TAB`?

Comment: personally I'm pissed that I can't use tab in a textarea. I think maybe yes, that is consistent from the browser form perspective but it's damn annoying. I expect to be able to tab just like in notepad or any other word editor.

Comment: @Timmerz, I'm with you. I would rather `CTRL+TAB` to cycle - but that's just because we're programmers and need tabs in code or markdown snippets. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the code I use on textareas to keep the TAB from switching focus:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e) {
  var $this, end, start;
  if (e.keyCode === 9) {
    start = this.selectionStart;
    end = this.selectionEnd;
    $this = $(this);
    $this.val($this.val().substring(0, start) + "\t" + $this.val().substring(end));
    this.selectionStart = this.selectionEnd = start + 1;
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: hi, ken Thompson, Could You Please Explain What is `this.selectionStart; and this.selectionEnd;` ?? i'm little confused about this statement.

Comment: It basically identifies the cursor position (assuming nothing is actually selected). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement

Answer (score 1):

You could

1. Use say 4 spaces to emulate tabs.
2. Have the user enter the "\t" character and treat it as a tab token to be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

[Tab Override](http://wjbryant.github.io/taboverride/) (my own project) enables tab functionality in textareas and also allows custom key combinations to be used. This way, the Tab key can continue to be used as normal.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Tabby jquery plugin to add this feature to a text area, works okay!

[Tabby](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/TextareaTabs)

With it you can use tab key to insert tabs in a text area. Though you do lose tab changing elements functionality.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to break the tab functionality. I need an alternative key-combo that can be used.